# How to overwrite HTTP Response Body C#

Tags: asp.net-core, exception, asp.net-web-api

I have created a middleware that allows me to intercept every call to my API. When the request is HttpStatus.Ok or HttpStatus.BadRequest, my code always returns the same type of response.
The middleware just "forward" the response without any changes

here is the standard response I have and wish to have in all cases :

```
{
"results": 0,
"numberOfRows": 1,
"requestGuid": "xxx",
"errors": [],
"StatusCode": 200,
"environment": "LOC"
}
```

My Api endpoint expects a number of properties via the Body. Some of the properties are mandatory.
If, for example, I send a call via postman and "forget" a mandatory property, I receive a standard message from the api, like this :

```
{
"errors": {
"MyProp": [
"The MyProp field is required."
]
},
"type": "https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.5.1",
"title": "One or more validation errors occurred.",
"status": 400,
"traceId": "xxx"
}
```

Normal message, but,this is the message that I want to standardise using my standard response.

here is the code of my middleware

```
public async Task InvokeAsync(HttpContext context)
{
try
{

                Stream originalBodyStream = context.Response.Body;
    
                await using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new())
                {
                    context.Response.Body = memoryStream;
    
                    await _next(context);
                    if (context.Response.StatusCode == 400)
                    {
                        //??
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        memoryStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                        string responseBodyText = await new StreamReader(memoryStream).ReadToEndAsync();
    
                       // memoryStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                        context.Response.Body = originalBodyStream;
                        await context.Response.Body.WriteAsync(memoryStream.ToArray());
    
                    }
    
                }
            }
            catch (Exception exception)
            {
                //todo
            }
        }
```

The else statement "forward" the response I have create, but I don't know how to send a new body  when I come into the if statement, the "standard" response is this object :

```
Response\<HttpStatusCode\> errorResponse = new()
{
StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.BadRequest,
Errors = new List\<ErrorsModel\>
{
new()
{
ErrorDetail = "test"
}
}
};
```

Comment: Is there anything else I can assist you on this? [you could have a look here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86978/how-do-i-accept-an-answer-on-stackoverflow) the next steps once any answer resolve your issue.

Answer (score 2):

> The else statement "forward" the response I have create, but I don't
> know how to send a new body when I come into the if statement, the
> "standard" response is this object

Generally, we should have a global request body variable where we can keep our initial request body for all the incoming request. For binding new response body all we need to have is serialized json data and a response class. It would be great if your response class would match the same property defination as your request class does.

Once we configure above steps then depending on the conditional we can easily override the existing request body or write new response body. Let's have a look on practice:

Custom Request Response Class:

```cs
public class ApiCustomRequestResponseClass
        {
            public string? ResponseCode { get; set; }
            public string? OldRequestBody { get; set; }
            public string? ResponseMessage { get; set; }
        }
```

**Note:** I am using it for the example. You can customize it based on your requirement.

Demo Controller:

```cs
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class OverrideRequestBodyController : ControllerBase
    {
       
        [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult OverrideRequestBody([FromBody] ApiCustomRequestResponseClass responseClass)
        {
            return Ok(responseClass);
        }
    }
```

Reponse Body Overring Middleware:

```cs
public class OverrideResponseBodyMiddleware
    {
        private readonly RequestDelegate _next;
        public OverrideResponseBodyMiddleware(RequestDelegate next)
        {
            _next = next;
        }
        public async Task InvokeAsync(HttpContext context)
        {
            var request = context.Request;
            var stream = request.Body;// At the begining it holding original request stream                    
            var originalReader = new StreamReader(stream);
            var originalContent = await originalReader.ReadToEndAsync(); // Reading first request
           

            if (context.Response.StatusCode == 200)
            {
               
                //My Custom Response Class
                var overringNewResponse = new ApiCustomRequestResponseClass();
                overringNewResponse.ResponseCode = "400";
                overringNewResponse.OldRequestBody = originalContent;
                overringNewResponse.ResponseMessage = "Here I am overring the request body";

                //converting my custom response class to jsontype
                var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(overringNewResponse);
                //Modifying existing stream
                var requestData = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(json);
                stream = new MemoryStream(requestData);
               
            }
            else {

                //Binding original data as it is
                var requestData = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(originalContent);
                stream = new MemoryStream(requestData);
               
            }
           
            //Writing the new response body with  modified steam of custom response
            request.Body = stream;

            await _next(context);
        }

    }
```

**Note:** For demo purpose I have overridden the response body within 200 status conditionals. Please modify as per your requirement.

Program.cs File:

```cs
app.UseMiddleware<OverrideResponseBodyMiddleware>();
```

Output:

[image]

**Note:** You can learn more details  about [Request and response operations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/middleware/request-response?view=aspnetcore-7.0) from our [official document here.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/middleware/request-response?view=aspnetcore-7.0)

Comment: Many thanks for the great, clear, precise answer.
Based on your example, with some modification I succeeded in using my middleware as I wanted

Comment: I'm unsure if I get it right. The question was on altering the body of the **response** but your code seems to manipulate the body of **request**, instead. What am I missing, please?

Comment: I tried to apply the similar approach on `context.Response.Body` but the stream reader got angry and said that the stream can't be read.